# How to build windows 8 mobile application in asp.net on window7 OS machine?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, windows, html

My Configuration is like this->

OS-  Windows 7 Professional

RAM - 8 GB.

Visual Studio - VS 2012 Ultimate.

Can I build windows-8 mobile apps with above configured machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't develop Windows Phone 8 apps on Windows 7, on Windows Server 2008, or on Windows Server 2012. 
The Windows Phone 8 Emulator has special hardware, software, and configuration requirements.
[System requirements for Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

[This link is also useful.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)